# Backbone JS error with 4.6.4 on WP messing up contribution page set up

Tags: javascript

It feels inappropriate posting this on Stack Exchange, but I don't see any other viable option since the support forum has been deprecated and no-one goes there any more, so here goes:

Just upgraded to 4.6.4 on a simple up to date Wordpress site. When setting up a contribution page the Receipting tab doesn't load correctly, the clickable fields that open up into CKEditor text areas don't work. I'm seeing a JS error in the Console: "TypeError: Backbone.Marionette is undefined" and a reference to line 11 of civicrm/js/crm.designerapp.js

Can't replicate on the demo site, but then again that is apparently not running 4.6.4, but 4.6.5.

Anyone?

Comment: Oh, and the 'Profiles' tab for the same contribution page is totally broken. There's no means of selecting a profile to be included in the contribution page.

Comment: Yea I think bug reports like this still belong on the forum. I don't think it's completely abandoned but this is certainly a transition period. I suggest you start with [this troubleshooting guide](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that newer versions of Marionette do not like the Backbone.Marionette.Application call, and would rather have Marrionette.Application.

So changing line 11 in civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.designerapp.js from:
CRM.designerApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
to:
CRM.designerApp = new Marionette.Application();
removes the error and allows the date picker lines to show correctly.

However, I'm unable to figure out what's changed to get the Profiles section to work, which is where the error:

TypeError: Backbone.CollectionSubset is not a constructor - (line 225, col 14)
subset = new Backbone.CollectionSubset(options);

in file civicrm/civicrm/packages/backbone/backbone.collectionsubset.js is coming from.  Seems like it may be a larger reworking will be needed, but I'm pretty much stabbing at the dark on all of this.

Answer (score 1):

On closer investigation, and with thanks to @coleman for referring me to the troubleshooting guide, I have successfully identified the culprit as the JetPack WP plug-in. With it de-activated, my contribution page set-up works without a hitch.

Comment: Graham, can you tell us which modules of JetPack you had active? It would help knowing which one is causing the problem.

Comment: FYI for googlers - we had exactly the same problem and traced it to WP Twitter Cards: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jm-twitter-cards/