# Backbone isn't loading on Civi 4.6.11/WP 4.4.1

Tags: civicontribute, backbone

UPDATE: Changing my theme seems to have fixed the problem - but I'm not sure how to fix the original theme.  Any advice on that issue is still welcome!

I'm seeing symptoms identical to this question: [Backbone JS error with 4.6.4 on WP messing up contribution page set up](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/backbone-js-error-with-4-6-4-on-wp-messing-up-contribution-page-set-up)

Pages using Backbone - particularly the "Include Profile" contribution configuration page - are broken, and the JS console says:

```
TypeError: Backbone.Marionette is undefined
TypeError: Backbone.CollectionSubset is not a constructor
```

However, the issue seems to be different than other folks experiencing it.  Here's what I've tried so far (including all at once):

- Disabling all WP plugins except CiviCRM.
- Disabling Summary Fields (the only CiviCRM extension in use).
- Clearing cache, deleting templates_c.

What else can I look for regarding this Backbone error?  I assume it's a collision with WordPress's Backbone, but I don't know enough about Wordpress to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've got this working - I didn't use Andrew West's technique above, but I still upvoted the answer as helpful.

The theme had this code in one of its includes:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'optionsframework_media_scripts' ) ) : 

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'optionsframework_media_scripts' );

function optionsframework_media_scripts(){
  if ( function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) ) 
    wp_enqueue_media();
  wp_register_script( 'of-media-uploader', OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY .'js/media-uploader.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'of-media-uploader' );
  wp_localize_script( 'of-media-uploader', 'optionsframework_l10n', array(
    'upload' => __( 'Upload', 'organizedthemes' ),
    'remove' => __( 'Remove', 'organizedthemes' )
  ) );
}

endif;
```

This was loading Backbone.  It also seems to be extraneous; the media uploader seems to work fine with this function commented out.

So I created a child theme, and in the `functions.php` file in my child theme, I added this code:

```
//put in a blank function here to override loading this function in the parent theme.
function optionsframework_media_scripts(){}
```

This worked great!  Ideally I'd like to copy the code from the child theme and add some conditional logic to say, "Only enqueue these scripts on a non-CiviCRM page" - but unfortunately that's beyond my Wordpress knowledge.

Comment: For a quick and easy hack I'd just check the URL for the civi basepage. 

Otherwise I *think* you could check to see if Civi has been initialized: ie "if (civicrm_initialize())" - but may want to test this one as I'm not 100% sure Civi would have initialized by that point in the theme processing.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* that when I had this it was caused by a theme loading a newer version of Backbone. Can you [dequeue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) the script in that theme's functions.php? And try queuing the Civi version direct? Admittedly a bit of a long shot.

Comment: yes, I'd reached similar conclusions as well - and tracked it down to Backbone being enqueued by the theme.  I'm currently creating a child theme so that I can address this, and based on your help, I'll use wp_dequeue_script() to do so.  As a WP novice, I have a question though:  Is there a good way to only call this dequeueing function if we're on a CiviCRM page?

Comment: @JonG did you get this worked out?  I THINK I worked out a tiny piece of the actual solution, but it's only half the problem and a tenth or less of the solution.  See:  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/backbone-js-error-with-4-6-4-on-wp-messing-up-contribution-page-set-up/11319#11319

Comment: @GH Yes, I got this worked out - see the answer I posted to this question.

Comment: @JonG, I did see your other answer, unfortunately the Salient theme doesn't have exactly the same problem.  I was hoping that you had found the code for this workaround.  I'll ping Andrew as I'm having trouble getting my mind wrapped around the specifics here.