# can't add profile to an event

Tags: civievent, profile

I have three environments that I can work in.

1. Production - the live site, currently 4.7.9
2. Development - a development site, currently 4.7.7
3. Staging - a sandbox, currently 4.7.9

I create an event in Production, go to the Online Registration tab. The "Include Profile (top of page)" label is there but the field is missing. The "Include Profile (bottom of page)" field is there as a text field (not a dropdown list). I can type in either the name of the profile or the profile ID, but the profile doesn't appear on the site web page, only the three default event fields (first name, last name and e-mail). The behavior on the Development site is the same.

When I create the same event/profile on the Staging (sandbox) site, the the "Include Profile" fields generates a dropdown list of current profiles and the profile fields correctly appear on the site web page.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 1):

This most often indicates a Javascript error - and in particular, this suggests a collision of Backbone.js with your CMS.  I suspect this question is actually a duplicate of mine here: [Backbone isn't loading on Civi 4.6.11/WP 4.4.1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9161/backbone-isnt-loading-on-civi-4-6-11-wp-4-4-1)

I should perhaps edit that question, since this appears to be a [common issue](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/dequeue-backbone-from-theme-load-and-load-civicrm-backbone) with certain WordPress themes that have a media loader.